# openvpn ip pool exhausted

Tags: openvpn, ip, pool

We have setup 3 OpenVPN servers (v2.4) in 3 different physical machines. 
They are all part of the same network.

When a client (v2.3) is connected we want him to go on either one of the VPN servers by using the "remote-random" flag (each server gives a different IP range)
The subnet on each server is /29

We also use the same certificate (for testing), thus "duplicate-cn" flag.

The problem is that when a client tries to connect multiple times to e.g vpn1 he gets assigned a different IP each time until there are no more IPs for the server to hand out.

At that point the client will establish a connection to the server but will not get an IP.

Is there any way to resolve this either either the server or the client side so that the client tries to connect to the other servers?

This VPN zone will be used temporarily for new clients which will be configured through puppet with a different VPN zone.

Comment: Why does the client connect multiple times? Why is your IP pool so small?

Comment: 1. I do not have many client devices to test..
2. this is a small pool which we want to use for devices that come online for the first time

Even with mre devices the problem would appear
The problem is that neither the client or the server does anything when 
a. the client does not get an IP (gets stuck there)
b. the server does not detect that there are no more available IPs and does not block the new connection

The problem would appear with more devices